# Error when i run this comand in react native project: expo install react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, google-maps, npm, expo, react-native-maps

i'm trying to run this comand in react native project: `expo install react-native-maps` .
However, it always return this error. I've tried to deleting node_modules and reinstall them, but the error lingers. Help me please, Thanks in advance !

```
    C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\Documents\Study\maps-react-native\react-native-maps>expo install react-native-maps
Installing 1 SDK 42.0.0 compatible native module using npm.
> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react-native-web@0.13.18
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!   react-native-web@"~0.13.12" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-web@"^0.11" from react-native-maps@0.28.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-maps
npm ERR!   react-native-maps@"0.28.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-29T20_29_51_765Z-debug.log



npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at NpmPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:166:31)
    at NpmPackageManager.addAsync (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:105:18)
    at actionAsync (C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\installAsync.ts:122:3)

C:\Users\ASUS TUFF\Documents\Study\maps-react-native\react-native-maps>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is due to npm v7.
Use below to install react-native-maps and it should work.

```
npm install react-native-maps --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and running `--legacy-peer-deps` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and installing with `--legacy-peer-deps` flag solved it.